# Can CERTS with missing organization (-O=name) cause browsers to not trust java keytool CERTs?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keytool

I have been setting up project that uses the Java keytool to generate a CSR for a PrivateKey. Another organization (not our commercial SSL CA) then generates 3 CRT files - 1 for the PrivateKey, and 2 for themselves. The problem is, our web browsers report that the CERTs are not trusted ('Not secure' in chrome, and 'This site is not secure' in IE).

Could missing organization (-O) or wrong unit (-OU) entries in the CSR cause this ?

Comment: No. For example, look at the cert for the site you are using right now, stackoverflow.com. It is issued by LetsEncrypt, and includes only CN (CommonName) in the Subject field, and is trusted. If this is a public server (which is often not the case when using a non-public CA) then https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest gives an analysis that includes fairly dumbed-down explanations of any problem with the cert _or_ other SSL/TLS characteristics.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for the information.